# HtmlAgilityPack ChildNodes skips tags <menu>

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to parse website 
I need to get all **menu** elements inside

```
string Url = "http://r-hockey.ru/";

var web = new HtmlWeb
{
    AutoDetectEncoding = false,
    OverrideEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251),
};

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);

HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@style='margin-left: 5px; vertical-align: top;'][@width='80%']");

if (nodes != null && nodes.Count == 1)
{
    var menuList = nodes.First();
    var list = menuList.ChildNodes.ToArray();
    ...
}
```

I can't get **menu** elements into **list**.
But they are in **menuList.Descendants()**. 
If I use jquery, i get them as children.

```
$("td[style='margin-left: 5px; vertical-align: top;'][width='80%']").children();
```

Obviously, my html is parsing wrong And I don't get, why. Please, help me.
I could've get menu tags from **menuList.Descendants()** but I need to store uppercased text after green dot and menu data at their correct order.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and it works fine. What are you getting inside the list?

Comment: Funny. I get only tags with names "#text", "style", "noindex" and "table".

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with google chrome and the structure I saw in "Inspect" was not the same as it was in "view page source"
So in my document **menu** was actually a child of **table** tag  inside my **td**.
Everything worked as it supposed to after I modified:

```
var menuList = nodes.First().SelectNodes(".//table").Last();
```